# If feature class is overlaped don't display its label

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6

I've got 2 polygon feature classes, one with countries and one with sectors of the countries.
How can I prevent country labels from rendering if I have sector classes overlaping them.
So how can you stop drawing labels over other feature classes, rather then over other feature class labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do this dynamically without scripting it yourself (you can ensure labels do not over lap, but that is not quite what you are asking for I think?)

If it is just for cartographic purposes an option would be to copy the label column in the attribute table, select by location all those with overlap and simply delete the labels for those with over lap (i.e. the label would then display blank).

Or you could intersect the geometries, select by attribute the combination you which wish to avoid and delete the label data in those fields.

Comment: Indeed this is the simpliest way to get the wanted result. Altrought I didnt want to modify the attributes to avoid accidents where I or my colegues forget to write back that information.

Answer (score 1):

I think weight of the feature is your option.

You can find that option under label manager > placement properties > conflict analysis
and set up value according to help below. (I don't have english version of ArcMap, but this most accurate names I can provide).

[A quick tour of the Labeling toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/a-quick-tour-of-the-labeling-toolbar.htm)

[A quick tour of labeling with the Maplex Label Engine](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/a-quick-tour-of-maplex.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_359C57A7CB924D9487AB336B842383AD)

[Help on labels weight, below is piece of it](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/weighting-labels-and-features.htm)

> Some common uses for weights:
>
> Prevents all labels from being placed on a given layer of point/line
> features or polygon outlines. Do this by increasing feature weight to
> High.
>
> Forces ArcMap to consider alternate positions for labels. Do
> this by increasing feature weight to Low or Medium.
>
> Prevents some
> labels from being placed on top of some features. Do this by
> increasing some feature weights and decreasing some label weights.
>
> If
> your data frame has annotation groups or annotation layers with
> nontext graphics, specify that labels be placed on top of these
> graphics by setting the feature weight for the layers and/or groups to
> None.

Comment: Ok, so Ive rewrite my comment to your answer a few times now, as Ive tried difrent aproces to the weight system.
Ive recently upgraded from ArcGIS 10.1 to 10.6.1, Ive tried this before, but buggie as it was I did'nt draw any conclusins back then.
Now after reading the documentation you've kindly provided Ive found out that, Labels care only about a ``polygons outline`` and not whats within it;
The order in the Table of Contents does not matter;
Normal or Maplex if the weight is not set to maximum the  the label with the low weight still displays even if it intersects the polygon outlines

Comment: And also from what I can tell the weight, at least for the future class acts as a buffer that grows acordingly.
At least untill the next case Im trying this in , where using the same settings I getting difrent results. Meaning eather Im not competent yet with this tool/future or its not reliable for my work.

Comment: Also Im using a normal liceence, but I did try an advanced one just to make sure I dont miss any options. Also in my english version its called "Conflict Resolution"